# Java Objects Problems

Tags: java, object

I have a doubt if i have function that returns the object that is hold in a class that already exists and do something like this:

```
    Class System{

    ...
    Vector<User> clients;
    ...
    }


    //In another class ...
    User c = getOwner(String username);
    c.add_value(balance);


   //Trasaction class
User owner;
   ....

public User getOwner() {
    return owner;
}
```

Does it change the values of the object that i returned and its hold in another class? or does it make a copy of that object?if so how can i make it to change the object and not make a copy of that object?

Comment: `User c = return_object_user(String username);` is not valid java; what are you doing? Can you update the code?

Comment: return_object_user is a function that i have created... but i have updated the code...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)

Comment: No thats is not similar as what i asked....

Comment: @exceltior: you think it's not, but it is the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all , I think you meant

```
User c = getOwner(username);
```

Now,

```
public User getOwner() {
    return owner;
}
```

In java, references to objects are passed by value. So, If you do

```
c.add_value(balance);
```

Yes, the object will be changed.